# How to add a custom view below the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to add a linear layout of view below the action bar, attached to it while scrolling. Something which makes the actionbar look like having 2 rows of views rather than one.

Adding a custom view is adding the view in the center of the actionbar and the search bar does not show up being overlapped.

Even if I increase the height of action bar, it won't help my case because I want the search bar to look like it's in a different view (and not on action bar).

Can I change the layout of action bar itself ? Or do I need to roll out my own custom action bar for this ?

[image]

Comment: Hi @SlowAndSteady. How did you add a custom view below the action bar?

Comment: I couldn't. Had to roll out my custom action bar.